# The perks and the pipeline for an LLVM based compilation

Tags: llvm

I see that more and more people are switching to LLVM, especially people with a background in C or C++, so there is a pattern in which kind of people are approaching this compiler, what surprises me is the highly heterogeneous set of technologies that LLVM can manage, and I don't get what is pipeline that this virtual machine follows and what are the resulting benefits.

I would like to stress the fact that I'm focusing on LLVM, not really on clang.

A 1 in a million example is [this one ( Youtube Video )](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ek-SkrGVyjY), where the pipeline is not really obvious for me, or [this other one](https://github.com/leaningtech/duetto-llvm), but apparently there a lot of totally different solutions where, for example, LLVM is used in conjunction with a JIT solution.

In short I see different syntax and semantics, people using LLVM to produce GPU shaders or binary objects, but I can't see the common denominator.

What is the meaning of "LLVM based compilation", Considering LLVM as a black box, what is the kind of input, output and the business logic in the middle ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't see the common denominator.

The common denominator is converting code in one language to code in another language. And that's exactly what compilers do. So if you want to convert a piece of code in a "source language" to one in a "target language", what you need to do is:

1. Write a "front-end" - a component that converts from your source language to what LLVM expects as input. That language is an LLVM-specific language called "LLVM Bitcode" or "LLVM IR".

   - Alternatively, reuse an existing front-end - for example Clang.
2. Write a "back-end" - a component that converts from what LLVM emits to your target language.

   - Or use an existing back-end, for example LLVM's x86 back-end.

That's it. Now you get to enjoy things like the optimizations LLVM performs on the code between its input and output, its common framework for "lowering" the code to something closer to machine code, etc.

GCC behaves the same, by the way, it's just that LLVM is considered by many to be superior in some aspects, particularly licensing and ease of modification.

Comment: ok, but, take the GLSL example, LLVM doesn't really know GLSL as a language, so I write a front-end for it, but if LLVM doesn't really know GLSL in the first place, how it can optimize my source code ? There is a guide for this stuff so I can read something about it ?

Comment: @user2485710 LLVM doesn't know C either, but it can still optimize it. The key is that it really only knows one language - its IR (intermediate representation) - but it can optimize it really well, so all you need to do is just convert to that IR. Most (if not all) optimizing compilers work this way - and as another example, the JVM is completely ignorant of Java (the language) - all it knows to run is Java Bytecode, which is also a form of intermediate representation.

Comment: I assume that this is why, for example, the Dalvik under Android can be used for both Java and C/C++/native code ? Could you recommend something to read that is about creating a frontend or a backend with LLVM ?

Comment: @user2485710 compilation is a wide field and if you're really interested I'd suggest taking a [course on compilation](https://www.coursera.org/course/compilers) or reading some [good basic book on the topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). If you want to jump right in, though, check out [this LLVM tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl1.html). For some info on backend design, check out [this backend-writing guide](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html), though keep in mind it's focusing on register-based machine-code generation.

Answer (score 2):

LLVM's advantage over other source-available compilers is that it is designed as a set of reusable libraries.  That means to some degree you can pick-and-choose what to include in your tool.  Not every language tool needs optimization and not every language tool needs code generation.  LLVM is a very flexible system for langauge processing.

Generally when people say, "LLVM based compilation," they mean using one or more of the LLVM libraries to implement their tool.  They can leverage all of the work put into LLVM in understanding its IR and generating code for multiple targets.

The LLVM IR is the common representation used by most of the LLVM libraries.  It is the interface you need to write to.  For low-level stuff like machine code you will need to deal with some of the other LLVM representations (MachineInstr, MC, etc.).

As for writing a frontend to generate that LLVM IR, the tricky part is ensuring that the translation from your source language to the LLVM IR preserves the semantics of the source language.  The LLVM IR has a well-defined but low-level set of semantics for each instruction.  If your source language has higher-level semantics you will have to lower them into LLVM IR instruction sequences to implement it.  For example, there is no LLVM instruction that handles C-style bitfield access so C language frontends must use a sequence of LLVM instructions to implement the functionality (generally shifts and bitwise operations).

As long as you implement the semantics of your source language in the LLVM IR correctly, the LLVM libraries will have no problem performing correct code transformations.  If some desired transformation requires higher-level semantics information than LLVM IR can provide, you either have to do the transformation in some stage before converting to LLVM IR (and so you will have the high-level information available) or you can pass attribute information in the LLVM IR to convey the high-level semantics and write a custom LLVM pass to implement the transformation.  It is usually far cleaner to do the former than the latter.